How to Intercept WooCommerce Coupon Apply Request for Rate Limiting Attempts by using a Hook?
I'm working on a WooCommerce site where I've implemented a rate limit for applying coupon codes. I created a separate database table to track user IPs and coupon usage through a function has_exceeded_coupon_attempts($email), which checks if a user has exceeded their allowed coupon attempts. Works fine, tested with
add_action('woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'track_coupon_attempts_jg8766576yGdf', 10, 1); 

Currently, I need a way / hook to execute this tracking function inside my functions.php file before the discount request is sent, ideally preventing the ajax form submission which request url looks like
...com/?wc-ajax=apply_coupon

from submitting if the rate limit is exceeded.
Are there specific hooks or filters that I should utilize for this purpose?
I appreciate any guidance or code examples that could help me achieve this. Thank you!

You could try to use woocommerce_coupon_is_valid filter hook, to add a custom validity step, intercepting the apply_coupon request, like:
add_filter('woocommerce_coupon_is_valid', 'track_coupon_validity', 10, 3);
function track_coupon_validity( $is_valid, $coupon, $discounts ) {
    $email = WC()->customer->get_billing_email(); // get billing email

    // add your logic below ($is_valid argument can be true or false)

    return $is_valid;
}

It could work, as this filter hook will prevent the coupon to be applied, displaying a generic error message.
To customize that generic error message, you can use woocommerce_coupon_error filter hook (with 3 arguments $error_message, $error_code and $coupon).

There are also 2 other available filter hooks, for coupon validation:

woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_cart (with 2 arguments: $is_valid and $coupon),
woocommerce_coupon_is_valid_for_product (with 4 arguments: $is_valid, $product, $coupon and $values).


just tested it, seems only to populate my db with and attempt entry if i enter a valid code but not if i let the field emtpy or input a wrong coupon code? i want to track all attempts regardless if a user enters a valid, invalid code or even no input.

The filter gets applied in WC_Discounts::is_coupon_valid(), but only after about a dozen other validations have already been performed, the first one of them being $this->validate_coupon_exists - and that already throws an exception when the coupon code is not found, so that will probably cancel any further steps.

seems there is no hook to intercept the submission unfortunately
